# Salesforce Contact Management

Tags: contact

I need to load contacts from a third party system without account details at the beginning. During the business process, those contacts may be assigned to new or existing accounts. I was wondering If this is good idea to load contacts without accounts during the initial phase. As far as I know, salesforce is account centric system so wanted to get your thoughts How it can be managed efficiently.

I looked at "PersonAccount" feature and it may not be an option as the contacts will be assigned to accounts eventually.

Comment: Are they definitely Contacts or are they Leads? Do you already know these people or are they, for example, an unqualified email list?

Comment: Take into account that Contacts that are not linked to an account are always private, regardless of your organization’s sharing model.

Comment: To work around the point Robin makes, you can create a default Account and set that initially.

Comment: @KeithC, I can create a dummy account but the volume is huge(about 40k per week). I think it will cause account skew after 100K so did not want to do that.

Comment: Yeah I wondered about that. Perhaps a new Account every week called e.g. "Default 15 Sep 2014" is a pragmatic solution to that...